# I can't get my collision code correct in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My collision code is really faulty because the red 'bullets' have to hit the exact middle of the player to run the game over screen. I need help refactoring the expression so if the red 'bullets' hit the player anywhere it will run my game over code (The game over code is near the end before pygame.quit())

```
import pygame
import random
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
pygame.init()
size = (700,700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Dodger")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def resetpositions():
    global bulletrect1, bulletrect2, bulletrect3, bulletrect4, bulletrect5, circlerect
    bulletrect1 = pygame.rect.Rect((350, 0, 20, 20))
    bulletrect2 = pygame.rect.Rect((175, 0, 20, 20))
    bulletrect3 = pygame.rect.Rect((525, 0, 20, 20))
    bulletrect4 = pygame.rect.Rect((525, 0, 20, 20))
    bulletrect5 = pygame.rect.Rect((525, 0, 20, 20))

circlerect = pygame.rect.Rect((350, 600, 20, 20))

resetpositions()
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            circlerect.x += 5
    bulletrect1.y += 1
    bulletrect2.y += 2
    bulletrect3.y += 3
    bulletrect4.y += 4
    bulletrect5.y += 5
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (circlerect.center), 15)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect1.center), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect2.center), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect3.center), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect4.center), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect5.center), 20)
    if bulletrect1.y == 800:
        bulletrect1.y = 0
        bulletrect1.x = random.randint(20,680)
    if bulletrect2.y == 800:
        bulletrect2.y = 0
        bulletrect2.x = random.randint(20,680)
    if bulletrect3.y == 800:
        bulletrect3.y = 0
        bulletrect3.x = random.randint(20,680)
    if bulletrect4.y == 800:
        bulletrect4.y = 0
        bulletrect4.x = random.randint(20,680)
    if bulletrect5.y == 800:
        bulletrect5.y = 0
        bulletrect5.x = random.randint(20,680)
    if circlerect.x == 685:
       circlerect.x = 15
    if circlerect.collidelist((bulletrect1, bulletrect2, bulletrect3, bulletrect4, bulletrect5)) == 0:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri',40,True,False)
        text = font.render("GAME OVER",True,RED)
        screen.blit(text,[250,350])
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(3000)
        resetpositions()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(300)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume all of your objects can be treated as circles? If so, you could just check if the distance between the centers of a given bullet (red circle) and player (green circle) is less than the sum of the radii of those two objects/circles.

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.Rect.collidelist`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) returns the index of the colliding rect in the list, that means you only check if the `circlerect` collides with the bulletrect at index `0`. It returns `-1` if no rects in the list collide, so if it doesn't return `-1`, one of the rects has collided with the player and the game is over:

```
if circlerect.collidelist((bulletrect1, bulletrect2, bulletrect3, bulletrect4, bulletrect5)) != -1:
    # Game over.
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept helpful answers to mark them as solved. Accepting an answer will give you 2 reputation points as well.